# How can i create a user modifiable XML document with python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I want to create this xml file and make it so i can modify it through the  terminal and add new "log" entries later.

This is the result i want after modifying it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hwlog.xslt"?>
<logroot>
  <log>
    <subject>Maths</subject>
    <timestart>12:00</timestart>
    <timeend>13:00</timeend>
    <timespent>1H</timespent>
    <worktype>Exercises</worktype>
    <workplace>home</workplace>
  </log>
  <log>
    <subject>Geo</subject>
    <timestart>14:00</timestart>
    <timeend>15:00</timeend>
    <timespent>1H</timespent>
    <worktype>Exercises</worktype>
    <workplace>home</workplace>
  </log>
</logroot>
```

This is my python script so far:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('hwlog.xml')

log = etree.Element("log")

subject = etree.SubElement(log, "subject")
timestart = etree.SubElement(log, "timestart")
timeend = etree.SubElement(log, "timeend")
timespent = etree.SubElement(log, "timespent")
worktype = etree.SubElement(log, "worktype")
workplace = etree.SubElement(log, "workplace")

titlesubjectinput = input("Subject : ")
titletimestartinput = input("Time Started : ")
titletimeendinput = input("Time Ended : ")
titletimespentinput = input("Time Spent [time ended - time started] : ")
titleworktypeinput = input("Work Type : ")
titleworkplaceinput = input("Work Place : ")

subject.text = titlesubjectinput
timestart.text = titletimestartinput
timeend.text = titletimeendinput
timespent.text = titletimespentinput
worktype.text = titleworktypeinput
workplace.text = titleworkplaceinput

outfile = open("hwlog.xml", "wb")
doc.write(outfile)
```

Although when i run this and enter, for example, (in order of prompt):
Geo, 14:00, 15:00, 1H, Exercises, home
the XML file comes out as:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hwlog.xslt"?><logroot>
  <log>
    <subject>Maths</subject>
    <timestart>12:00</timestart>
    <timeend>13:00</timeend>
    <timespent>1H</timespent>
    <worktype>Exercises</worktype>
    <workplace>home</workplace>
  </log>
</logroot>
```

which is obviously not how i want it. How can i make it so it can come out like what i want (1st XML example)?

please excuse my terrible programming skills, i am a "noob".

Comment: *This is the result i want after modifying it*...modifying it from what? Where's the original input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append then new log-Element:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('hwlog.xml')

log = etree.SubElement("log")
etree.SubElement(log, "subject").text = input("Subject : ")
etree.SubElement(log, "timestart").text = input("Time Started : ")
etree.SubElement(log, "timeend").text = input("Time Ended : ")
etree.SubElement(log, "timespent").text = input("Time Spent [time ended - time started] : ")
etree.SubElement(log, "worktype").text = input("Work Type : ")
etree.SubElement(log, "workplace").text = input("Work Place : ")

doc.getroot().append(log)
with open("hwlog.xml", "wb") as outfile:
    doc.write(outfile)
```